# Вопрос по SQL-запросу

Tags: mysqli

Вроде как и простой запрос, но что-то сделать не получается, выводится единица.

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT SUM(`allball`) FROM `views` WHERE `id_user`='".$user['id']."' AND `id_firm`>'0' AND `time` > '".(time()-86400)."'")->num_rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ршение:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT SUM(`allball`) as `all` FROM `views` WHERE `id_user`='".$user['id']."' AND `id_firm`>'0' AND `time` > '".(time()-86400)."'")->fetch_array();
```